# Ag-grid Master/Detail grid Independent pagination at Master and Detail

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, nested-gridview

if number of rows of detail grid are more, it is tedious to scroll through all rows, 
Is it possible to add pagination at Master and Detail independently?

I have gone through the below link of ag-grid documentation but did not find a way or mention of pagination.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add pagination related properties `pagination : true` to the detail grid options. Here is what your `detailGridOptions` would look like -

```
this.detailCellRendererParams = {
  detailGridOptions: {
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'callId' },
      { field: 'direction' },
      {
        field: 'number',
        minWidth: 150,
      },
      {
        field: 'duration',
        valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'",
      },
      {
        field: 'switchCode',
        minWidth: 150,
      },
    ],
    defaultColDef: { flex: 1 },
    pagination : true, //set pagination to true
    paginationPageSize: 5 // define page size, default is 100

  },
  getDetailRowData: function(params) {
    params.successCallback(params.data.callRecords);
  },
};
```

}

Attaching the example screenshot -

[image]

Used this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#example-simple)